# Sample Script sample limit?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a script that takes a sample from each category in an excel file. There are different percentages taken, depending on the length, but I was wondering if there is a way to set a limit of 5 items per sample, even if the 1% brings back, say, 2 items. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\****\Desktop\Audit_catalogs\****.xlsx")

df2 = df.loc[(df['Track Item']=='Y')]
print(len(df2))

def sample_per(df2):
    if len(df2) >= 15000:
        return (df2.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.01)))
    elif len(df2) < 15000 and len(df2) > 10000:
        return (df2.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.03)))
   else:
    return (df2.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.05)))


final = sample_per(df2)

df.loc[df['Retailer Item ID'].isin(final['Retailer Item ID']), 'Track Item'] = 'Audit'

df.to_csv('****_Audit.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: for every group you could calculate manually `size*0.01`  and use `if/else to run `sample(n=5)` instead of `sampe(frac=0.01)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `x.size * 0.01` to check how many values you can get and use `sample(n=5)` instead of `sample(frac=0.01)`

```
.apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=5) if x.size*0.01 < 5 else x.sample(frac=0.01))
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(1) #  to generate always the same random data

data = {'Category': [random.choice([1,2,2,2,3]) for x in range(1000)]} # columns
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# --- before ---
df1 = df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.01))
print('--- before ---')
print(df1['Category'].value_counts())

# --- after ---
df2 = df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=5) if x.size*.01 < 5 else x.sample(frac=0.01))
print('--- after ---')
print(df2['Category'].value_counts())
```

Result

```
--- before ---
2    6
3    2
1    2
Name: Category, dtype: int64

--- after ---
2    6
3    5
1    5
Name: Category, dtype: int64
```

---

**EDIT:** The same in more readable way

```
def myfunction(x):
    if x.size*0.01 < 5:
         return x.sample(n=5)
    else:
         return x.sample(frac=0.01)

df1 = df.groupby('Category').apply(myfunction)
```

Comment: Thank you! Just so I'm clear, the line (.apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=5) if x.size*0.01 < 5 else x.sample(frac=0.01))) says to take 5 samples from the category, but if 1% is more than 5, take 1% of the items in that category?

Comment: yes, if 1% of some group will gives les then 5 samples then It gets 5 samples. I add more readable version at the end of answer.